# Cloned Jessie image fails to acquire a dhcp address

Tags: networking, raspbian-jessie, dhcp, backup, restore

I have a very nasty issue with Jessie :-(

Background:
I wrote a tool called raspiBackup which backups and restores a Raspberry and because it works fine for me and helped me multiple times to recover from a SD card failure I decided to publish it. It's already used by a lot of people.

Issue:
When I restore the clone/backup of **Wheezy** created with tar the system comes up with an IP address.

When I restore the clone/backup **Jessie** created with tar the system doesn't receive an IP from my local dhcp server. If I start the original image everything works fine.

When I restore the clone/backup **Jessie** created with **rsync** the system  works fine.

Backup options used with rsync: -rlptgoDWDEHAXx

Backup options used with tar: -cp --selinux --acls --xattrs

I also compared the two logs /var/log/syslog from the original Jessie system saved with tar and the restored Jessie system which doesn't get an IP.

Original image:

```
Jun 22 19:10:58 jessie-small avahi-daemon[336]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::93ca:50ee:da9d:3d04.
Jun 22 19:10:58 jessie-small kernel: [   14.543974] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Jun 22 19:10:58 jessie-small kernel: [   14.549440] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jun 22 19:10:58 jessie-small avahi-daemon[336]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun 22 19:10:58 jessie-small avahi-daemon[336]: Registering new address record for fe80::93ca:50ee:da9d:3d04 on eth0.*.
Jun 22 19:10:58 jessie-small dhcpcd[331]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Jun 22 19:10:59 jessie-small kernel: [   16.252955] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
Jun 22 19:10:59 jessie-small kernel: [   16.257045] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jun 22 19:10:59 jessie-small dhcpcd[331]: eth0: carrier acquired
Jun 22 19:10:59 jessie-small dhcpcd[331]: DUID 00:01:00:01:20:7e:13:d4:b8:27:eb:f7:28:f5
Jun 22 19:10:59 jessie-small dhcpcd[331]: eth0: IAID eb:b4:e8:74
Jun 22 19:11:00 jessie-small dhcpcd[331]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jun 22 19:11:00 jessie-small dhcpcd[331]: eth0: rebinding lease of 192.168.0.100
Jun 22 19:11:01 jessie-small kernel: [   18.250280] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
Jun 22 19:11:05 jessie-small dhcpcd[331]: eth0: leased 192.168.0.100 for 864000 seconds
Jun 22 19:11:06 jessie-small dhcpcd[331]: eth0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24
Jun 22 19:11:06 jessie-small dhcpcd[331]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1
Jun 22 19:11:06 jessie-small avahi-daemon[336]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.100.
Jun 22 19:11:06 jessie-small avahi-daemon[336]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jun 22 19:11:06 jessie-small avahi-daemon[336]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.100 on eth0.IPv4.
Jun 22 19:11:06 jessie-small dhcpcd[331]: forked to background, child pid 542
Jun 22 19:11:06 jessie-small systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Jun 22 19:11:06 jessie-small systemd[1]: Starting Network.
```

Cloned image:

```
Jun 22 19:10:25 jessie-small avahi-daemon[336]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::e41d:db7e:7264:fadb.
Jun 22 19:10:25 jessie-small kernel: [   16.584421] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Jun 22 19:10:25 jessie-small kernel: [   16.590118] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jun 22 19:10:25 jessie-small avahi-daemon[336]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun 22 19:10:25 jessie-small avahi-daemon[336]: Registering new address record for fe80::e41d:db7e:7264:fadb on eth0.*.
Jun 22 19:10:25 jessie-small dhcpcd[335]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Jun 22 19:10:25 jessie-small systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: control process exited, code=killed status=11
Jun 22 19:10:25 jessie-small systemd[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Jun 22 19:10:25 jessie-small systemd[1]: Unit dhcpcd.service entered failed state.
Jun 22 19:10:25 jessie-small systemd[1]: Starting Network.
```

Command executed on cloned Jessie:

```
systemctl status -l dhcpcd.service
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
           └─wait.conf
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2017-06-22 22:13:35 CEST; 1min 58s ago
  Process: 334 ExecStart=/sbin/dhcpcd -q -w (code=killed, signal=SEGV)

Jun 22 22:13:32 jessie-small dhcpcd[334]: version 6.7.1 starting
Jun 22 22:13:33 jessie-small dhcpcd[334]: eth0: adding address fe80::e41d:db7e:7264:fadb
Jun 22 22:13:35 jessie-small systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: control process exited, code=killed status=11
Jun 22 22:13:35 jessie-small systemd[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Jun 22 22:13:35 jessie-small systemd[1]: Unit dhcpcd.service entered failed state.

Warning: Unit file changed on disk, 'systemctl daemon-reload' recommended.
```

I found out you can fix the dhcp issue on the cloned image by starting the dhcp server manually to get an IP from the local DHCP server and then uninstall and install the dhcp client again with

```
sudo dhcpcd eth0
sudo apt-get remove dhcpcd5
sudo apt-get install dhcpcd5
```

Unfortunately you need console access and a connected monitor which is very inconvenient because raspiBackup is used most of the time on headless systems.

Another solution is to use networkd on Jessie.

It seems somehow be related to systemd which is new in Jessie and the different way a backup is created with tar and rsync.

Does somebody have an idea what's the root cause for the issue? My goal is to have the restored Jessie image to start again like the original image with an IP without any workarounds.

**Update 6/25**

I started two Raspis - the original and the clone image, enabled debug on dhcp and extracted all dhcp messages from /var/log/syslog.

I noticed

```
Jun 25 16:49:20 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: udev: starting
Jun 25 16:49:20 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: dev: loaded udev
```

is missing in the clone image. Looks like the interface is not started :-(

```
Jun 23 20:33:15 jessie-small dhcpcd[351]: version 6.7.1 starting
Jun 23 20:33:15 jessie-small dhcpcd[351]: eth0: disabling kernel IPv6 RA support
Jun 23 20:33:15 jessie-small dhcpcd[351]: eth0: adding address fe80::e41d:db7e:7264:fadb
Jun 23 20:33:15 jessie-small dhcpcd[351]: eth0: pltime infinity, vltime infinity
Jun 23 20:33:15 jessie-small dhcpcd[351]: eth0: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' PREINIT
Jun 23 20:33:15 jessie-small dhcpcd[351]: eth0: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' NOCARRIER
Jun 23 20:33:17 jessie-small dhcpcd[351]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Jun 23 20:33:17 jessie-small systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: control process exited, code=killed status=11
Jun 23 20:33:17 jessie-small systemd[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Jun 23 20:33:17 jessie-small systemd[1]: Unit dhcpcd.service entered failed state.
```

```
Jun 25 16:49:20 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: version 6.7.1 starting
Jun 25 16:49:20 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: udev: starting
Jun 25 16:49:20 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: dev: loaded udev
Jun 25 16:49:20 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: eth0: disabling kernel IPv6 RA support
Jun 25 16:49:20 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: eth0: adding address fe80::e41d:db7e:7264:fadb
Jun 25 16:49:20 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: eth0: pltime infinity, vltime infinity
Jun 25 16:49:20 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: eth0: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' PREINIT
Jun 25 16:49:20 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: eth0: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' NOCARRIER
Jun 25 16:49:21 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Jun 25 16:49:21 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: eth0: carrier acquired
Jun 25 16:49:21 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: eth0: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' CARRIER
Jun 25 16:49:21 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: DUID 00:01:00:01:20:dc:fd:c0:b8:27:eb:d6:a6:c9
Jun 25 16:49:21 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: eth0: IAID eb:d6:a6:c9
Jun 25 16:49:21 jessie-small-06 dhcpcd[357]: eth0: delaying IPv6 router solicitation for 0.2 seconds
```

**Update 7/13:** This is an important issue for me. That's why I posted the same question in this [forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=188282&sid=994164b3bb0b465722566723892d1a64) and consider that post as the primary post for my issue from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that there aren't any dhcpcd lease files getting cloned? While DHCPv4 identifies clients by MAC48, a cloned lease file may cause problems with some DHCP servers. For reference, my FritzBox differentiates identically cloned RPis by their digferent MAC48s, but on DHCPv6 you get strange results due to the cloned DUID that is independent of the leases.

Comment: I see. That's another difference between Wheezy and Jessy I didn't know about: dhcpv4 vs dhcpv6. I executed 'sudo rm /var/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd*.lease' and rebootet the system but it didn't get an IP :-(

Comment: I've only now noticed in your log file for the cloned image that the dhcpcd service fails. What does `sudo systemctl status -l dhcpcd.service` report? This should show the output of the dhcpcd service (unit).

Comment: I also missed that you are cross-cloning between Wheezy and Jessie ... don't! This will never work, because Wheezy is init-based, Jesie is systemd-based. Also, dhcpcd in Wheezy is 4.x, in Jessie it's 6.x wroth lots of differences, you should notice from the different places for configuration files, et cetera ... dhcpcd versus dhcpcd5.

Comment: I added the output in my question above.

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean by crosscloning. I have one raspi1 up and running with Jessie, cloned this one to another SD card, put this SD card into another raspi1 and booted the clone. There is no Wheezy in charge. 
I mentioned Wheezy because I don't have this issue with Wheezy. It's just an issue with Jessie :-(

Comment: I never run into any issues with cloning Jessie using either the built-in rpiclone or a github-supplied rpi-clone script, the latter doing the same as the former, but without GUI, so it can be used via ssh. Just make sure to have different hostnames set in case you intend to boot the clone on a different piece of hardware, as otherwise most home routers end up mapping the same hostname simultaneously to multipe IPv4 addresses, the latter beeing assigned individually to each MAC48 address.

Comment: rpiclone is a nice tool but misses a lot of features. For example raspiBackup can create dd, tar in addition to rsync backups and much more. Please note: raspiBackup can save and restore Jessie images using rsync. The issue pops up with a tar backup. That's why you didn't face the issue with rpiclone.
I added the tar and rsync parms used for backup because this also may be the root cause for the issue :-)

Comment: I just did a `sudo tar -cvzf RPi0_root.gz` with the latest updates on Jessie and restored it with `sudo tar -xvzf RPi0_root.gz` without any dhcp issues. I did read that "AppArmor and SELinux differ radically from one another ..." and that AppArmor is available on Debian-base  platforms ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux). Have you tried `tar` without the `--selinux flags`? (Just a thought.)